# Debug a VBA Script that highlights similarities in text strings:

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, similarity

Here is a sample of the code that I currently have. The image shows the results I am currently getting and what I need to have. I need to compare one string in a cell to a whole row of cells, but this script only allows me to select one column at a a time. I am not a coder and need help finding the issue. See my work below.

[SEE CURRENT RESULTS <<<-- CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvXT8.png)

```
Sub highlight()
    Dim xRg1 As Range
    Dim xRg2 As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell1 As Range
    Dim xCell2 As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim xLen As Integer
    Dim xDiffs As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
      xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
      xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
lOne:
    Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg1.Columns.Count > 1 Or xRg1.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo lOne
    End If
lTwo:
    Set xRg2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", "Kutools for Excel", "", , , , , 8)
    If xRg2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If xRg2.Columns.Count > 1 Or xRg2.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo lTwo
    End If
    If xRg1.CountLarge <> xRg2.CountLarge Then
       MsgBox "Two selected ranges must have the same numbers of cells ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
       GoTo lTwo
    End If
    xDiffs = (MsgBox("Click Yes to highlight similarities, click No to highlight differences ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Kutools for Excel") = vbNo)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xRg2.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    For I = 1 To xRg1.Count
        Set xCell1 = xRg1.Cells(I)
        Set xCell2 = xRg2.Cells(I)
        If xCell1.Value2 = xCell2.Value2 Then
            If Not xDiffs Then xCell2.Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            xLen = Len(xCell1.Value2)
            For J = 1 To xLen
                If Not xCell1.Characters(J, 1).Text = xCell2.Characters(J, 1).Text Then Exit For
            Next J
            If Not xDiffs Then
                If J <= Len(xCell2.Value2) And J > 1 Then
                    xCell2.Characters(1, J - 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Else
                If J <= Len(xCell2.Value2) Then
                    xCell2.Characters(J, Len(xCell2.Value2) - J + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of what you want to achieve instead of leaving it as a puzzle for the reader?

Comment: See the embedded image. I want to the macro to refer to one column of reference values, and check for similarities within the corresponding columns in the same row. Currently, it is only highlighting one similarity in one string and I am not sure why

Comment: I looked at the image _before_ posting my comment. The logic is far from obvious. in the first line of your desired result, why should the "A" be highlighted, but not the "N".

Comment: Oh,  because that is the letter I am searching for in the string within that row. Sorry if that wasn't clear at first. I needed to label the columns

Answer (score 2):

Try this - assuming your search terms are in Col A starting in A1

Adjust as necessary.

```vb
Sub HiliteSubstrings()

    Dim c As Range, cCheck As Range, txt, v
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pos As Long, st As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    
    'loop the strings to search for
    For Each c In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        txt = Trim(c.Value) 'find this
        If Len(txt) > 0 Then
            'loop all values to the right of the search string cell
            For Each cCheck In ws.Range(c.Offset(0, 1), ws.Cells(c.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
                v = cCheck.Value                           'value to search in
                st = 1                                     'reset search start position
                Do
                    pos = InStr(st, v, txt, vbTextCompare) 'case-insensitive
                    If pos > 0 Then                        'got a match?
                        cCheck.Characters(pos, Len(txt)).Font.Color = vbRed
                        st = pos + 1                       'increment start position
                    End If
                Loop While pos > 0                         'loop while have a hit
            Next cCheck
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you